# Does Azure Mariadb/Mysql data-in replication support certificate chains?

Tags: replication, mariadb, azure

I would like to migrate from AWS RDS Mysql to Azure Mariadb managed database.

For this purpose, I would set up data-in replication using TLS, roughly following the provided [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mariadb/howto-data-in-replication#link-the-source-and-replica-servers-to-start-data-in-replication).

AWS [provides](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport) certificate chains, for RDS servers. Does Azure data-in replication support certificate chains?

Answer (score 0):

Testing myself, directly providing the chain does not work.
It raises the error:

```
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'MASTER_SSL_CA' at row
```